# Problem with output of simple if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement

**Right now this is my code:**

```
test_score = 500
print(important_aspect)
print()
important_aspect = '"%s"' %important_aspect
print(important_aspect)

if important_aspect == "\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.":
    test_score = test_score + 100

print (test_score)
```

**The output is the following:**

```
\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.

"\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk."
500
```

**How can I make sure the python reads the `important_aspect` data equal as the data in the if-statement, so the output will be 600? The data from the important_aspect variable comes from a cel in an excel file saved as csv.**

Comment: The code you've shown for the value of `important_aspect` is not valid Python, so it's hard to tell exactly what the desired behavior is here.  Please edit your post to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you missed the quotes for the string `important_aspect`, check this:

```
important_aspect = "\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk."
```

**Updated version for edited question:**

You can use string literals for comparing with raw string `r`

```
test_score = 500

string_for_compare = r"\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk."

if important_aspect == string_for_compare:
    test_score = test_score + 100

print(test_score)
# 600
```

This is because escape characters, if you print string for comparing without `r` for example you get:

```
Vrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' Uitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' Verbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.
```

Comment: @Diew, no problem, please mark the right answer with the solved status

Comment: I have a new problem now, its not working yet. I changed it in the question. Do you understand why its not working?

Comment: @Diew, sure, can you check updated version, you can use string literal

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce:

```
test_score = 500

important_aspect = r"\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk."

if important_aspect == r"\x7fVrijheid: Ik wil mijn eigen acties en keuzes maken. Ik wil autonomie hebben.', ' \x7fUitdaging: Ik wil mij competitief en effectief voelen.', ' \x7fVerbinden: Ik wil mij verbinden met anderen. Multiplayer games zijn daarom belangrijk.":
    test_score = test_score + 100

print (test_score)
# 600
```